# Inconsistent behaviour when selecting multi-select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal dialog which has a multi-select form element. On screen, I have two buttons - each with different options associated with them (one associated with 'Admins' and the other associated with 'Users')

When the user clicks on any button, jQuery identifies which option the button is associated with and then pre-selects the option on the multi-select list element in the modal dialog. All good thus far. The function works if I do it once - but if I do it repeatedly or select one button and then another button the option doesnt appear pre-selected. Am unable to identify where the bug is.

Any insight is appreciated - [link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chicagosky/02g22qxk/13/)

The jQuery code is below - not sure why this is behaving in an inconsisten manner if I randomly select the buttons

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function () {

    $('.modal-body #name').val('John');

    $('.modal-body #email').val('john@acme.com');

    var groupNames = $(this).data('group-names');
    $('.modal-body #groups > option').each(function () {
        if (groupNames.search($(this).text()) == 0) {
            $(this).attr('selected', true);
        } else {
            $(this).attr('selected', false);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just setting the value of the `<select>` using `val()`. It's far simpler than looping over each option

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function () {
    var groupNames = $(this).data('group-names');
    $('.modal-body #groups').val(groupNames);
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/02g22qxk/15/)**</kbd>

Comment: 2 questions - 1. Will this work if a button has more than one group associated with it? In other words - a multi-select scenario. 2. The actual value associated with these options is different from the text that appears - so when the user submits the modal form - will this approach not create a problem for the form processor? I just tried changing the group-names value to have 'Admins,Users' and this didnt work - if I have multiple options then I will hvae to loop - or am I incorrect?

Comment: use the value as data, not the text. For multiple can pass array to `val()` and data attribute can also be array

Comment: Note that for array in data attribite it has to be valid JSON, so either needs escaping or use single quotes to wrap array http://jsfiddle.net/02g22qxk/18/ I used single quotes

Comment: you could also use any delimiter you want without making this JSON and use `split(delimiter)` to create array from string value in data attribute

Comment: I'm confused by one part of your answer - you said use value as data not text - can you please explain what you mean by this.

Comment: instead of JSON array can do something like `data-group-names="Users,Admins"` then create array with `split(',')`

Comment: Ok - to clarify what I was asking - I updated the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/chicagosky/02g22qxk/22/ - please see this. Basically, if I use the `val()` method then I should pass underlying values and not display text - it doesnt work as demonstrated in the fiddle. Do you have any suggestion for a workaround that allows me to select based on the display text? Hopefully I am clear with this question

Comment: ok got it - that is what i suspected - i have to pass values if the values are pre-populated. I cannot pass values and expect it to select based on the display text - thanks - this clarifies a lot and you have been a lot of help. Hopefully someone else finds this useful as well

Comment: general rule of thumb is should always have `value` attribute on `<option>` and set no value as empty string. I think that's where some of the confusion may have started since we were using text as value

Answer (score 0):

@charlietfl 's response is the best approach.  But the reason your code works inconsistently (in some browsers) is that you should set the selected property instead of attribute, like this:

```
$(this).prop('selected', 'selected');
```